# Statistical testing where each participant has many measurements of the same variable

Tags: anova, clustering, repeated-measures

I am trying to find the best way to handle my situation whereby I have 4 distinct populations that differ according to clinical diagnosis, roughly 100 people in total. There are 120 measurements of a single variable for each patient, over 8 variables. I want to compare variable distributions between groups/populations and test if there are significant differences between them. I can't just add up all measurements for each individual within each group and compare the group distributions because then the samples aren't all independent.

From what I have read so far, I am choosing between a repeated measures mixed model or 2 stage clustering, but I am really not sure because repeated measures seems to assume that these variables depend in some integral way on time whereas the reason I have so many instances of them is more to do with making sure we have an accurate representation of their distribution. I am unsure about clustering because I would like to be able to run some statistical test or find out in some way if we can differentiate the different populations based on their parameter values/variables. I was also considering just taking the mean of all values for a given person, and then running statistical tests, but I am not sure that is rigorous enough.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to a mixed design with repeated measures. Take the mean (or median) over the 120 samples for each variable since time appears irrelevant.